# SQL join conditions order performance

Tags: sql, performance, join, firebird

Does JOIN conditions order affect pefrormance? I have two tables A and B. I'm trying to join them like that:

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B on B.ID_A = A.ID
```

In this case firebird use `NATURAL` plan instead using foreign key.

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B on A.ID = B.ID_A
```

works good.

Is that normal?

Comment: no affect in inner join but you use left join and right join then affected performance.

Comment: Which Firebird version do you use? I've never seen such a problem with Firebird, so maybe it is just a bug in one of the versions...

Comment: @MaximVotyakov  I'm using Firebird 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you use Firebird with version older than 2.5.4 (probably 2.5.3). And it had bug  http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-4530 fixed in 2.5.4. Please upgrade to Firebird 2.5.5 and check whether your problem disappear.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with firebird but usually it doesn't matter for inner join.
And in the new version of Oracle or SQLServer or MySQL or Postgresql it won't impact the performance. we have explain plan to check the Database choose the right way to Join you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

This query is OK, but make sure `B.ID_A` is index, (for Fast performance)

Don't use `*` in sql query, use only required columns...

Your question is about performance, so i am thinking, you have very large data..
so Must use `LIMIT` with your query...

Example

```
SELECT A.ID, A.column1, B.column2, FROM A
INNER JOIN B on B.ID_A = A.ID  LIMIT 0,100
```

Comment: I wrote `*` there just for example. As I know Firebird creates an index for foreign key automatically. But it doesn't use this index in first case.